# What have I misunderstood about keras layer sizes?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, keras-layer

As part of getting to know deep learning and Keras, I am trying to implement the following pipe line:

[image: EEG analysis net from https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01683]

The idea is:

- input sections of EEG data ( 6000x1 is what I will use for now)
- run that through 20 1D filters (200x1)
- do max-pooling on the output of each of these filterings with pool 20, stride 10 (resulting in 20 578x1 data points)
- "stack" this into a 578x20 matrix
- run this through a 2D convolution with kernel size 30x20
- Maxpool again, with pool (10,1), stride(2,1)
- two consecutive fully-connected layers
- 5-class softmax function.

My code is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(input_shape=(6000,1),kernel_size=200,strides=1,
             activation='relu',filters=20,name='C1'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=20, strides=10,padding='valid',name='P1'))
model.add(Reshape(( 579, 20,1),name='S1'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=400,kernel_size=(30,20),strides=(1,1), 
             activation='relu',name='C2'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(10,1),strides=(2,1),padding='valid',name='P2'))
#model.add(Reshape((271*400,1,1),name='S2'))
model.add(Dense(500,activation='relu',name='F1'))
model.add(Dense(500,activation='relu',name='F2'))
model.add(Dense(5,activation='relu',name='output'))
model.add(Activation(activation='softmax',name='softmax'))

model.summary()
```

The output of this is:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
C1 (Conv1D)                  (None, 5801, 20)          4020      
_________________________________________________________________
P1 (MaxPooling1D)            (None, 579, 20)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
S1 (Reshape)                 (None, 579, 20, 1)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
C2 (Conv2D)                  (None, 550, 1, 400)       240400    
_________________________________________________________________
P2 (MaxPooling2D)            (None, 271, 1, 400)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
F1 (Dense)                   (None, 271, 1, 500)       200500    
_________________________________________________________________
F2 (Dense)                   (None, 271, 1, 500)       250500    
_________________________________________________________________
output (Dense)               (None, 271, 1, 5)         2505      
_________________________________________________________________
softmax (Activation)         (None, 271, 1, 5)         0         
=================================================================
Total params: 697,925.0
Trainable params: 697,925.0
Non-trainable params: 0.0
_________________________________________________________________
```

And this is where I get confused. I would like the output of F1 to be simply 500x1 (500 neurons), but that is not what I get at all? Should there be another reshape-layer between P2 and F1? Adding "model.add(Reshape((271*400,1,1),name='S2'))" after P2 does not do anything about the problem.
I have "image_data_format": "channels_last" in keras.json, so I assume that my dimensions are batch - row - col - channel?

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Try swapping your reshape with a Flatten layer with model.add(Flatten())
https://keras.io/layers/core/#flatten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand how the Dense layer works. It's a bit counter intuitive but if your input has more than 1 dimension (other than the batch dimension), then it will act like a dense layer distributed on the last dimension.

If you look in the [doc of the Dense layer](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense), you see that for an input shape `(batch_dim, dim1, dim2,..., last_dim)` you get an output shape `(batch_dim, dim1, dim2, ..., output_units)`.

Which means in your case, when you do a `Reshape((271*400,1,1),name='S2')`, the dense layer will be applied on the last dimension and output something like this `(271*400,1,500)`. If you want the output to be `(500,)` then the output of S2 should be a 1D tensor containing all the features. You should then do `Reshape((271*400,),name='S2')` or `Flatten()` as @maz is saying in the comments. `Flatten()` is a reshape that takes all the values of any tensor and put them in a 1D tensor.

I hope this helps :-)